# Using return redirect makes authentication data changes Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

So below here, notice that I use `return redirect('/home')`.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'filled|email',
        'password' => ['filled', Password::min(8)->numbers()]
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('account')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }

    return redirect('/login')->withErrors('User not found');
}
```

However, when I `dd(Auth::guard('account')->user());` it shows like this:
[attributes list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smn9H.png)

Notice that the account_id is "ABC", but actually, it is supposed to be "mdd" as I log in with "mdd" email and password. This, however, doesn't happen if I use this (use return view instead of return redirect):

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'filled|email',
        'password' => ['filled', Password::min(8)->numbers()]
    ]);

    if (Auth::guard('account')->attempt($credentials)) {
        return view('home', [
            'title' => 'Home'
        ]);
    }
    
    return redirect('/login')->withErrors('User not found');
}
```

And this is my route for redirecting to '/home'.

```
Route::get('/home', [AccountController::class, 'viewHome']);
```

The viewHome():

```
public function viewHome()
{
    // dd(Auth::guard('account')->user());
    return view('home', [
        'title' => 'Home'
    ]);
}
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Oh yes the image that I gave is actually laravel always take my first database row data as the authenticated one, which makes authentication data being different from I logged in...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
            $input = $request->all();
    
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);
    
            $fieldType = filter_var($request->email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'email';
            if(auth()->attempt(array($fieldType => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
            {
                return redirect('home');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('message', 'User not found');
            }
    
        }
```